# Definition file for extended prototype

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am in the process of converting a number of Javascript files to Typescript files in a project. Currently, I have been working to convert Range3.js, a file that depends upon another Javascript file named Cartesian3.js I wrote a definition file (d.ts) for Cartesian3.js, and the project compiles, but at runtime, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cartesian3 is not defined
```

Cartesian3.js is formatted like this:

```
define([
    './TypescriptFile'
    ],
function(
    TypescriptFile
    )
{
    /* file has some prototype-extending functions like this */
    Cesium.Cartesian3.prototype.extendingFunction = function()
    {
        /* function defined here */
    }

    /* and some static functions like this */
    Cesium.Cartesian.staticFunction = function()
    {
        /* function defined here */
    }

    /* more functions... */

    return Cesium.Cartesian3;
});
```

The d.ts file I wrote for Cartesian3.js looks like this:

```
///<reference path="../../Cesium/Cesium.d.ts"/>
declare class Cartesian3 extends Cesium.Cartesian3 {
    extendingFunction(): void;
    static staticFunction(): Cartesian3;
    /* more functions listed here */
}
```

Range3.ts (the file that throws the ReferenceError) looks like this:

```
///<reference path="./Cartesian3.d.ts"/>
/* another import */

class Range3
{
    low: Cartesian3;
    /* more instance variables */

    /* truncated constructor */
    constructor(low?: Cartesian3)
    {
        this.low = Cesium.defined(low) ? <Cartesian3>low.clone() : new Cartesian3; // line that throws an error
    }

    /* more functions */
}
```

Range3.js (which works with the project) looks like this:

```
define([
    './Cartesian3',
    /*another dependency*/
    ],
function(
    Cartesian3,
    /*other dependency */
    )
{
    function Range3(low)
    {
        this.low = Cesium.defined(low) ? low.clone() : new Cartesian3();
    }
    /* other functions defined here */
    return Range3;
});
```

I suspect this is due to an incorrect implementation of the definition file but I can't pinpoint the issue. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the error is at runtime, I don't think the definition file would affect it. Are you including all the appropriate .js files?

Comment: yes, Cartesian3.js is included, and so is Cesium's library

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a solution, but I found a workaround. Since the Javascript file was extending the prototype of a Cesium object (Cartesian3), I added the extra functions to Cesium's d.ts file for Cartesian3, and removed Cartesian3.d.ts, instead referencing Cesium.d.ts in Range3.ts, which fixed the error. Should anyone care to find a better solution, I would love to know.